# Combine rows by similar post code using an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to combine rows when the start of a postcode matches.

I have the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Billing Zip` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total Customers` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total Spent` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total Orders` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total Items` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Returning Customers` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39171 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A UK postcode can be 5 or 6 characters. So in terms of combining similar post codes it may be best to start from the end and exclude the last 3 characters?

Here's some of my test data:

```
id  Billing Zip Total Customers Total Spent Total Orders    Total Items Returning Customers
1   cf24 4ay    27  52.91   13  17  2
2   NP20 3SE    11  154.15  27  57  3
3   N10 1EA 5   369.05  39  129 2
4   SE18 4HJ    5   421.35  18  156 3
5   E9 9AF  5   553.02  55  194 4
6   CF10 4NQ    5   136.36  27  53  3
7   BS4 3AQ 4   80  9   26  2
8   EH15 2NE    4   172.8   29  56  2
9   cf24 7NL    4   380.7   37  115 3
10  TR10 9AH    4   103.43  14  30  3
11  E9 6QH  4   44.82   8   17  1
```

I want to combine any rows where the start of the postcode is the same and total the rest of the columns.

So for example, row 1 and row 9 should be combined as they start with cf24. The same for row 5 and 11 as they start with E9.

Is that possible with an SQL query, if so, how can I do it?

---

Expected outcome - it should just combine any rows where the start of the postcode matches

```
id  Billing Zip Total Customers Total Spent Total Orders    Total Items Returning Customers
1   cf24    31  433.61  50  132 5
2   NP20 3SE    11  154.15  27  57  3
3   N10 1EA 5   369.05  39  129 2
4   SE18 4HJ    5   421.35  18  156 3
5   E9  9   597.84  63  211 5
6   CF10 4NQ    5   136.36  27  53  3
7   BS4 3AQ 4   80  9   26  2
8   EH15 2NE    4   172.8   29  56  2
9   TR10 9AH    4   103.43  14  30  3
```

---

Attempt causing error for nonaggregated column:

```
select (case when min(billing_zip) = max(billing_zip) then min(billing_zip)
             else substring_index(billing_zip, ' ', 1)
        end) as billing_zip,
       sum(total_customers),
       sum(total_spent),
       sum(total_orders),
       sum(total_items),
       sum(returning_customers)
from postcodes
group by substring_index(billing_zip, ' ', 1);
```

Comment: 1. Can you please post what is your expected should look like for the above mentioned two rows. 2. Please tag the database type also.

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula Sorry just updated the question with the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the start of the code using `substring_index()`:

```
substring_index(postalcode, ' ', 1)
```

For your full solution, though, you need some tricks on aggregation:

```
select (case when min(postalcode) = max(postalcode) then min(postalcode)
             else substring_index(postalcode, ' ', 1)
        end) as postalcode,
       sum(total_customers),
       . . .    -- whatever aggregation functions you want for them
from t
group by substring_index(t.postalcode, ' ', 1);
```

Note:  You have defined your columns with spaces in the names.  I strongly encourage you to use underscores instead (i.e. `total_customers` rather than `total customers`) so the names do not need to be escaped in queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted my column names. I've updated my question with the attempt, I'm getting the error: 

`Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tester.postcodes.billing_zip' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Error code 1055.`

Comment: @Rob . . . In your `group by`, use `group by postcodes.billing_zip`.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted that part. Is there any way to slightly tweak what it's doing? At the moment it's splitting the postcode by a space, is there a way to just ignore the last 3 characters instead? Then group them that way? Reason being, there's mix of postcodes with a space and not, I've removed all the spaces.

Comment: @Rob . . . That would be a different question from the one you originally asked and should be asked as a *new* question.  But you can probably use something like `left(billing_zip, length(billing_zip) - 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables by this:

```
regexp_substr(substr(TRIM(postalcode), 1, 2), '[A-Za-z]+', 1, 1)
```